# Why do we need a curve to be parametrised by arclength to get $(\ddot{y},\dot{y})=0$?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry

Why do we need a curve to be parametrised by arclength to get $(\ddot{y},\dot{y})=0$? Shouldt this be true either way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider the curve $\Gamma:[0,1]\rightarrow\textbf{R}^{n}$. If the curve is parametrized by its arclength, we have $\lVert\Gamma^{\prime}\rVert = 1$. Therefore we have
\begin{align*}
\lVert\Gamma^{\prime}\rVert^{2} = \langle\Gamma^{\prime},\Gamma^{\prime}\rangle = 1 \Longrightarrow 2\langle\Gamma^{\prime\prime},\Gamma^{\prime}\rangle = 0 \Longleftrightarrow \langle\Gamma^{\prime\prime},\Gamma^{\prime}\rangle = 0
\end{align*}

Indeed, for every constant $k > 0$ such that $\lVert\Gamma^{\prime}\rVert = k$ the result follows.

Comment: The first equivalence isn't true as it is. It suffices to have constant length

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I would edit it, but you were faster than me.

Comment: Didn't you answer a different question then OP asked? You proved that arc length parametrization implies that $\langle y'', y' \rangle=0$, OP asked why we need arc length parametrization in order to get $\langle y'', y' \rangle=0$. This can be answered with some small modifications of your answer.